# Google AppEngine python webapp2 session ignores cookie in Android app

Tags: android, google-app-engine, session, cookies

I have an app engine server that uses webapp2 extras auth mechanism. I have both an Android and an iOS client, and of course the mechanism uses cookies in order to keep the session going.

The problem is, that the when the Android client tries to make a request after logging in - even if it sends the a request with the cookie - the cookie is ignored and the session is not recovered. When I use the iOS client - the session is verified successfully.

This is very bizarre and I can't put my finger on why this happens.

I debugged the session for both cases, and here they are:

iOS session:

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Language: en-us
Content_Length: 0
Content_Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
Cookie: auth="eyJfdXNlciI6WzQ2Nzg2OTY4NTQwOTM4MjQsMSwiV3FmUnFWUmxUME91TllsYnZsMWFxOSIsMTQyMzM1MzI3MCwxNDIzMzUzMjcwLCJMaW9yIFphdGxhdmkiXX0\075|1423353270|c2c7343dbb701f188c18f8b16c0fe06b794ad2d2"
Host: localhost:8081
User-Agent: PeersCards/1.0 CFNetwork/711.1.12 Darwin/14.0.0
X-Appengine-Country: ZZ
INFO     2015-02-08 17:38:55,123 user_api.py:591] Session was recovered
```

Android session:

```
Content_Length: 0
Content_Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8
Cookie: auth=eyJfdXNlciI6WzQ2Nzg2OTY4NTQwOTM4MjQsMSwiZDBCam5Sc1lucElRTjMySWxKQ0NzZyIsMTQyMzQxOTI1MSwxNDIzNDE5MjUxLCJMaW9yIFphdGxhdmkiXX0\075|1423419251|68063593b0262fdb5c6b479457c95eb9fcc7047f
Host: 10.0.0.16:8081
User-Agent: Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.2; SM-N900 Build/KOT49H)
X-Appengine-Country: ZZ
INFO     2015-02-08 18:16:11,215 user_api.py:594] Session is not saved
```

Any ideas?

Comment: In your shoes, I'd start hacking `logging.debug` calls into webapp2 sources (in the local dev server, assuming the problem is reproducible there -- if not you'll need to clone webapp2 into your source tree to do the same) to find out in detail what's going on in each case, the succeeding and the failing one; nothing leaps out to me from the logging entries you show us...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured this out.

Apparently, the Android CookieManager was storing the cookie as:

```
auth=XXXXXX
```

And AppEngine was expecting:

```
auth="XXXXX…"
```

It can also be seen in the input I've placed in the question, though I seriously didn't think that would be the issue.

I've set the `""` manually into the cookie in the Android code, and that worked out the problem.